# Why does the chrome browser no longer show busy?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

On this device, I am using chrome Version 109.0.5414.120 (Official Build) (64-bit).

I've noticed that it's got a weird behavior where there is absolutely no indication that the browser is busy, regardless of the website.

No spinning wheel, no mouse pointer turned into a wheel, nothing.  The tab icon itself on a new page looks like this.
[image]

So basically, I open the browser, type in the address, and wait for a couple of seconds (maybe 8 max if it's a slow website).
I'm looking at a blank browser page, no indication it's busy - absolutely nothing... while I'm wondering if there's a problem, it suddenly loads the page.

Compared to Edge browser which does this

[image]

Ideas?

PROGRESS:
As suggested, I tried incognito mode. No problem. The busy indicator appears as expected.

If I then go back to the normal browser (open in the background) it now works properly.

Close everything and start again - problem re-occurs.

So basically if I want the busy indicator, I must open a second window incognito, and close it, then all is well.

I have no extensions. This is a new system. Win10. OS Build 19044.2486

Comment: I saw a comment somewhere about maybe some script in the page changing this behavior... but I'm talking every single page in every circumstance, without fail.

Comment: The issue might be something you changed with the New Tab page, maybe using some browser extension. Try the same in Incognito or a Guest window

Comment: Good idea... Incognito mode works as expected. circular rotating icon is showing

Comment: I was able to confirm Chrome 109 does have a loading icon, it's different than the one Edge uses, but it does exist and does show that the tab is loading.

Comment: @Maxcot, in that case you should try to disable all browser extensions and see if it's good. Then enable one by one, and test

Comment: I have no extensions